# I can not connect my Android device to a local database with REST API

Tags: android, rest, xamarin, httpclient, postman

My need: connect my Android device to a local SQL Server database.
My problem: an exception occurs when trying to connect ("An error occurred while sending the request")
What I use: Visual Studio 2017 and Xamarin Forms with MVVM architecture.
What works: I do a POST from Postman and it works perfectly, returning the user's token.
My project uses a REST API to connect to the DB. The API is published as FileSystem and run with IISExpress and as I said, with Postman it works.
I have tried:
http://localhost:50965
http://192.168.1.106:50965 (my PC IP)

My connection string on API Web.config

```
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=192.168.1.106; Initial Catalog=Gesuro; Integrated Security=True; User ID = sergio; Password=xxxxxxxx" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

My call to the API:

```
        var token = await this.apiService.GetToken(
            "http://localhost:50965",
            this.Email, 
            this.Password);
```

My API method:

```
    public async Task<TokenResponse> GetToken(
        string urlBase,
        string username,
        string password)
    {
        try
        {
            var client = new HttpClient();
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(urlBase);
            var response = await client.PostAsync("Token",
                new StringContent(string.Format(
                "grant_type=password&username={0}&password={1}",
                username, password),
                Encoding.UTF8, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"));
            var resultJSON = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TokenResponse>(
                resultJSON);
            return result;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            var pepe = e.Message;
            return null;
        }
    }
```

I've been searching Google for three days and trying different solutions ... without results.
I hope I have been specific with my query. Some help, please?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am not sure if Xamarin has the same issue as plain Android, which is: To connect to localhost via physical device your device and PC has to be connected to same internet (preferably Wi-Fi), but you could try changing `localhost` to ip: `10.0.2.2` and try running an emulator ir Xamarin has such thing.

Comment: the db is local to what, the device?

Comment: You can also try using [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) tool, to simulate real server for short period of time. It will generate random URL for you, then you just swap out `localhost` to whatever URL `ngrok` generated and try your luck with calling the API then.

Comment: do NOT use localhost.  Use the IP or FQDN.  And be sure IIS is setup to allow remote connections.

Comment: As I wrote in my post, I have already tried to connect to my IP PC, in addition to localhost. The DB is local to PC. I tried also with emulator.

When I return to my home I will try the solutions that you propose to me.

Comment: Are you testing this on device or emulator?

Comment: I tried the device. But after a week without solving it, I directly hired a azure account, created the sql server database there and I can develop it calmly. The solution will remain pending ...

Answer (score 2):

Try changing `compile using Android version (Target Framework)`
Change it android 6.0 might work

I faced the same issue changing the target framework solved this for me.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't provided enough details, but I'm going to guess.
Your db server is running on your PC, then run

```
$ adb reverse tcp:50965 tcp:50965
```

on it, and then when you access

```
localhost:50965
```

on your device it will be redirected to same port on your PC

#### EDIT

If you want to test that `reverse` works, do

```
$ adb reverse tcp:3456 tcp:80
```

and if you are running a web server on port 80 on your PC when you open **Chrome** on the device and enter

```
http://127.0.0.1:3456
```

you will see the home page

Comment: Thanks, Diego, but this does not work either.
adb work ok, but I receive the same error.